# How would I seed an object that has a list of other objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a Pizza class:

```
public class Pizza
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

And an Ingredient class:

```
public class Ingredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Pizza> Pizza { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using EF 6 with data migrations, and I want to seed the database. Only problem is, how do I approach this? I have the following code in my configuration class:

```
 protected override void Seed(PizzaBoerContext context)
 {
     context.Pizzas.AddOrUpdate(i => i.Name,
         new Pizza
         {
             Name = "Margherita",
             Description = "",
             Image = "PizzaMargherita",
             Ingredients = new List<Ingredient>()
             {
                 new Ingredient() { Name = "Tomatensaus", Description = "Gemaakt van tomaten" },
                 new Ingredient() { Name = "Kaas", Description = "Gemaakt van melk" },
                 new Ingredient() { Name = "Oregano", Description = "Gemaakt van plant" },
             },
             Price = 6.00M
         },
         new Pizza
         {
             Name = "Funghi",
             Description = "",
             Image = "PizzaMargherita",
             Ingredients = new List<Ingredient>()
             {
                 new Ingredient() { Name = "Tomatensaus", Description = "Gemaakt van tomaten" },
                 new Ingredient() { Name = "Kaas", Description = "Gemaakt van melk" },
                 new Ingredient() { Name = "Champions", Description = "Een soort schimmel" },
             },
             Price = 6.00M
         }
         );
      }
```

See, the ingredients need to be put in the database as well. Do I put them first, or can I go about it like this? Is EF smart enough to know to populate the ingredients table as well? And how can I avoid duplicates?

UPDATE

I modified the seed to the following code:

```
protected override void Seed(PizzaBoerContext context)
    {
        var margharita = new Pizza {
            Name = "Margherita",
            Description = "",
            Image = "PizzaMargherita",
            Ingredients = new List<Ingredient>(),
            Price = 6.00M
        };

        var funghi = new Pizza
        {
            Name = "Funghi",
            Description = "",
            Image = "PizzaFunghi",
            Ingredients = new List<Ingredient>(),
            Price = 8.00M
        };

        var tomatoSauce = new Ingredient() { Name = "Tomatensaus", Description = "Gemaakt van tomaten" };
        var cheese = new Ingredient() { Name = "Kaas", Description = "Gemaakt van melk" };
        var oregano = new Ingredient() { Name = "Oregano", Description = "Gemaakt van plant" };
        var mushroom = new Ingredient() { Name = "Champignon", Description = "Een soort schimmel" };

        margharita.Ingredients.Add(tomatoSauce);
        margharita.Ingredients.Add(cheese);
        margharita.Ingredients.Add(oregano);

        funghi.Ingredients.Add(tomatoSauce);
        funghi.Ingredients.Add(cheese);
        funghi.Ingredients.Add(mushroom);

        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
```

The only problem is, is that the tables aren't being filled. What am I missing?

Comment: To prevent duplicates you probably need to separately seed the ingredients.